# How to get the difference between two maps Java?

Tags: java, collections, set

I have two maps as below :

```
Map<String, Record> sourceRecords;
Map<String, Record> targetRecords;
```

I want to get the keys differ from each of the maps.i.e.

1. It shows mapping keys available in sourceRecords but not in targetRecords.
2. It shows mapping keys available in targetRecords but not in sourceRecords.

I did it as below :

```
Set<String> sourceKeysList = new HashSet<String>(sourceRecords.keySet());
Set<String> targetKeysList = new HashSet<String>(targetRecords.keySet());

SetView<String> intersection = Sets.intersection(sourceKeysList, targetKeysList);
Iterator it = intersection.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Object object = (Object) it.next();
    System.out.println(object.toString());
}

SetView<String> difference = Sets.symmetricDifference(sourceKeysList, targetKeysList);
ImmutableSet<String> immutableSet = difference.immutableCopy();
```

**EDIT**

```
if(sourceKeysList.removeAll(targetKeysList)){
            //distinct sourceKeys
            Iterator<String> it1 = sourceKeysList.iterator();
            while (it1.hasNext()) {
                String id = (String) it1.next();
                String resultMessage = "This ID exists in source file but not in target file";
                System.out.println(resultMessage);
                values = createMessageRow(id, resultMessage);
                result.add(values);
            }
        }
        if(targetKeysList.removeAll(sourceKeysList)){
            //distinct targetKeys
            Iterator<String> it1 = targetKeysList.iterator();
            while (it1.hasNext()) {
                String id = (String) it1.next();
                String resultMessage = "This ID exists in target file but not in source file";
                System.out.println(resultMessage);
                values = createMessageRow(id, resultMessage);
                result.add(values);
            }
        }
```

I am able to find the common keys but not distinct keys. Please help.

Comment: Are you looking for Guava's `Sets.symmetricDifference(source.keySet(), target.keySet())`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sets allow you to **remove** elements as well.

If generating "helper" sets is not a problem for you (because of too many entries; what about:

```
Set<String> sources = get a copy of all source entries
Set<String> targets = get a copy of all target entries
```

then:

```
sources.removeAll(targets) ... leaves only entries in sources that are only in sources, not in target
```

whereas

```
sources.retainAll(targets) ... leaves only entries that are in both sets
```

You can work your way from here ...

Comment: set1.retainAll(set2) will provide the mapping keys in both the sets. But for  set1.removeAll(set2), it will remove the keys that are in set2 from set1. I want the way to do the same for set2 also.

Comment: And what prevents you to do the reverse "removing" on set2?

Comment: I applied the same, see the edited question but didnt solve my problem

Comment: I really do not understand your problem. If you do: A-B; you get A-B; and when you do B-A; you get B-A. Of course, the one point to be aware of is that you should be making copies of A B for those remove operations.

Comment: got it thanks.. exactly this was the problem. Before removing i have to make a copy which i missed.

Answer (score 32):

You can use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [`Maps.difference(Map<K, V> left, Map<K, V> right)`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#difference(java.util.Map,java.util.Map)) method. It returns a [`MapDifference`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapDifference.html) object, which has methods for getting all four kinds of map entries:

- equally present in left and right map
- only in left map
- only in right map
- key present in both maps, but with different values

So in your case, it could be solved with only 3 lines of code:

```
MapDifference<String, Record> diff = Maps.difference(sourceRecords, targetRecords);
Set<String> keysOnlyInSource = diff.entriesOnlyOnLeft().keySet();
Set<String> keysOnlyInTarget = diff.entriesOnlyOnRight().keySet();
```

Comment: How to get difference for nested values, for example 
{val1: {val2: {val3: 1, val3:2}}} and {val1: {val2: {val3: 5, val3:2}}}, Here, difference is at val3's value and its hierarchy is val1:val2:val3.

Comment: @PriyalJain That should be asked as its own question, check [ask].

Answer (score 5):

You may use a copy `Set` and `removeAll` :

```
Set<String> difference = new HashSet<String>(sourceKeysList);
difference.removeAll(targetKeysList);
```

See [The Set Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. It shows mapping keys available in sourceRecords but not in targetRecords.

`sourceKeysList.removeAll(targetKeysList)`

2. It shows mapping keys available in targetRecords but not in sourceRecords.

`targetKeysList.removeAll(sourceKeysList)`

Comment: The above code prints only difference in targetKeyList but not in sourceKeyList. Editing the question as per the instructions, applied but didnt solve my problem.