# Java 8 : Filter 2 different JSON arrays according to certain fields

Tags: java, json, filter, java-stream

This may be silly but I couldn't figure it out, I have 2 different schema JSON arrays.

**JSON array A**

```
[
  {
     "name": "Robin",
     "uid": 1234   
  },  
  {
     "name": "Tom",
     "uid": 8768   
  },   
  {
     "name": "Eddy",
     "uid": 4534   
  }
]
```

**JSON array B**

```
[
  {
     "group": "Reign",
     "admin": 8768   
  },  
  {
     "group": "Hounds",
     "admin": 1234   
  },   
  {
     "group": "Dukes",
     "admin": 5996   
  }
]
```

Essentially the values of **uid** in JSON array A and **admin** field in JSON array B are same. The lists are very large so iteration is very expensive.

My task is to get the elements of Array A matches with elements of Array B according to these 2 fields (uid & admin). Also need to collect  excess elements of Array A and excess elements of Array B.

What I have done so far

```
List<JsonObject> listOutput = jsonDataAList.stream()
                .filter(e -> jsonDataBList.stream()
                        .map(JsonDataA::getUid)
                        .anyMatch(admin -> admin.equals(e.getAdmin())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Down voters please find time for any explanation

Thank in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JacobG. jsonDataAList.stream().filter(e -> jsonDataBList.stream().map(JsonDataA::getUid).anyMatch(admin -> admin.equals(e.getUid()))).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Do you need it for initial use or would you be parsing it every time?

Comment: @DhruvSehgal I will have both arrays parsed into List<JsonObject> as ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself

```
private List<JsonObject> getExcessElements(List<JsonObject> primaryList, List<JsonObject> secondaryList, String primaryKey, String secondaryKey) {
List<JsonObject> excessInPrimary = primaryList.stream()
.filter(e -> (secondaryList.stream()
.filter(d -> d.get(secondaryKey).equals(e.get(primaryKey)))
.count()) < 1)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
return excessInPrimary;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `uid` is unique I would convert both Jsons to `Map<Integer, String>` and then use next [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42950187/9046830)

> You can use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s
>   [`Maps.difference(Map<K, V> left, Map<K, V>
>   right)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#difference-java.util.Map-java.util.Map-)
>   method. It returns a
>   [`MapDifference`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapDifference.html)
>   object, which has methods for getting all four kinds of map entries:
>
> - equally present in left and right map
> - only in left map
> - only in right map
> - key present in both maps, but with different values