# Java Differences between maps including values

Tags: java

I need to find only differences between 2 maps, while the different can be by missing key or by different value for key.

I find a general answer for [Differences between maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015282/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-maps-java)

> ```
> sources.removeAll(targets) ... leaves only entries in sources that are only in sources, not in target
> ```
>
> whereas
>
> ```
> sources.retainAll(targets) ... leaves only entries that are in both sets
> ```

But I'm not sure it's better than the following code, because I need to check apart from key existence also that the values are different

```
    Map<K, V> updatedMap = new EnumMap<>(K.class);
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> finalSet : secondMap.entrySet()) {
        K currentKey = finalSet.getKey();
        if (!firstMap.containsKey(currentKey) || firstMap.get(currentKey) != finalSet.getValue()) {
            updatedMap.put(currentKey, finalSet.getValue());
            firstMap.remove(currentKey);
        }
    }
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> currentSet : firstMap.entrySet()) {
        K currentKey = currentSet.getKey();
        if (!secondMap.containsKey(currentKey)) {
            updatedMap.put(currentKey, currentSet.getValue());
        } else if (secondMap.get(currentKey) != currentSet.getValue()) {
            updatedMap.put(currentKey, secondMap.get(currentKey));
        }
    }
```

Is their a better way of finding the differences between maps including values?

Comment: how about `.entrySet()` and using guava `Sets.symmetricDifference`?

Comment: @Eugene I currently don't use guava, but you can answer

Comment: before I do that suppose `leftMap = [{1, "one"}, {2, "two"}]` and `rightMap = [{1, "uno"}, {2, "duo"}]` what expected result you have in your mind? `[{2=two}, {1=one}, {2=duo}, {1=uno}]`?

Comment: @Eugene only values from secondMap [{2=uno}, {1=duo}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could compare `Entry`s from a `Map`, because that class overrides `equals/hashCode` in the manner that you want. It's not entirely clear which entries you would want to keep, the ones from the *left map* or the *right map* or any of them.

For example this could be done via :

```
Map<Integer, String> allDifs = 
             Sets.symmetricDifference(left.entrySet(), right.entrySet())
                 .stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

On the other hand if you just want to keep entries form the second (right) `Map`:

```
 Map<Integer, String> result = 
             Sets.difference(right.entrySet(), left.entrySet())
                 .stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));

    System.out.println(result);
```

Obviously you need `guava` and `java-8` for this...

**EDIT**

what you actually want is not achievable with `Collectors.toMap`, but you can do it with:

```
    Map<Integer, String> result = new HashMap<>();
    Sets.symmetricDifference(right.entrySet(), left.entrySet())
            .stream()
            .forEachOrdered(x -> {
                String previousValue = result.putIfAbsent(x.getKey(), x.getValue());
                if (previousValue != null) {
                    result.replace(x.getKey(), right.get(x.getKey()));
                }
            });
```

Comment: I have guava in jersey dependency  so I'll check it

Comment: `symmetricDifference` is almost what I need, but I got in testing `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key NA`

Comment: @user7294900 that is probably happening because you have two `Key` as `NA`, so `Collectors.toMap` fails... in this case - what do you want to do when duplicate keys are present? this is something you need to think of. for example you could have the result as `Map<String, List<String>>` to keep duplicate key values in a `List`, or always keep the *first* (or *last*) one... so which one is it?

Comment: Second map value should overcome/override

Answer (score 1):

## Use Guava's [`Maps.difference(Map, Map)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#difference-java.util.Map-java.util.Map-).

[Their wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#difference) explains how it works, but you can find below the solution to your problem.

```
Map<String, Integer> left = ImmutableMap.of("a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3);
Map<String, Integer> right = ImmutableMap.of("b", 2, "c", 4, "d", 5);
MapDifference<String, Integer> diff = Maps.difference(left, right);

Map<String, Integer> output = new HashMap<>();
output.putAll(diff.entriesOnlyOnLeft());
output.putAll(diff.entriesOnlyOnRight());
for (Map.Entry<String,MapDifference.ValueDifference<Integer>> e: diff.entriesDiffering().entrySet()) {
  // Java 10 and later : for (var e: diff.entriesDiffering().entrySet())
  output.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue().rightValue());
}
System.out.println(output); // {a=1, c=4, d=5}
```

Comment: I want a map with only differences where second is overriding first map, in your example with (a,1 ,c ,4 ,d ,5)

Comment: If you have two maps, `left` and `right`, you know which elements only from `left` you want, and don't want, and the same for `right`. All you have to do is to take `entriesOnlyOnLeft()`. I'll update my answer with your exact requirements.

Comment: I use java 8 (not 9) and your code doesn't compile: there are no `.entries()` and `.getRight()`

Comment: @user7294900 Fixed it. I made too many shortcuts and didn't test. The current code is entirely tested.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I think I'll choose `symmetricDifference` which saves more code lines