# Compare nested JSON object with Java with differences

Tags: java, json

Does anybody know how to compare two JSON files in java and show their differences? I have tried using guava by following this example: [How to compare JSON documents and return the differences with Jackson or Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967015/how-to-compare-json-documents-and-return-the-differences-with-jackson-or-gson)

Do note that the naming of arrays in the JSON like "institution", "people" and "details" are not fixed.

The results of this attempt produce these:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> type = 
    new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};

Map<String, Object> leftMap = mapper.readValue(leftJson, type);
Map<String, Object> rightMap = mapper.readValue(rightJson, type);

MapDifference<String, Object> difference = Maps.difference(leftMap, rightMap);
System.out.println(difference.entriesDiffering());
```

Output

```
{institution=([{school=TP}], [{school=MIT}]), details=([{duration=4, course=Humanities, description=Students in Computer Sci}], [{duration=4, course=Computer Sci, description=Students in Computer Sci}]), people=([{name=Bob, age=32}, {name=Amanda, age=16}], [{name=Bob, age=32}, {name=Samantha, age=16}, {name=Dylan, age=20}])}
```

Left JSON

```
{
"package": {
  "institution": [
      {
        "school": "TP"
      }
    ],
    "people": [
      {
        "age": 32,
        "name": "Bob"
      },
      {
        "age": 16,
        "name": "Amanda"
      }
    ],
    "details": [
      {
        "course": "Humanities",
        "duration": 4,
        "description": "Students in Computer Sci"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Right JSON

```
{
"package": {
  "institution": [
      {
        "school": "MIT"
      }
    ],
    "people": [
      {
        "age": 32,
        "name": "Bob"
      },
      {
        "age": 16,
        "name": "Samantha"
      },
      {
        "age": 20,
        "name": "Dylan"
      }
    ],
    "details": [
      {
        "course": "Computer Sci",
        "duration": 4,
        "description": "Students in Computer Sci"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected Output

```
Differences
institution = {"school": "MIT"}
people = {"age": 20, "name": "Dylan"}, {"age": 16, "name": "Samantha"}
details = {"course": "Computer Sci"}
```

Comment: The given output is correct. If you want custom behaviour/output then you need to write custom code, or rather than doing a top-level difference call you need to further process the inner JSON elements rather than comparing top level elements. You might also find the answers here helpful: [How to get the difference between two maps Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015282/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-maps-java)

Comment: How do I manipulate the output of the entriesDiffering to display only differences of one map instead of both?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/octomix/josson

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.octomix.josson/josson

This method subtract left JSON from right JSON. It compares the whole object inside an array, instead of comparing individual object value inside an array.

```
implementation 'com.octomix.josson:josson:1.3.21'

------------------------------------------------


Jossons jossons = new Jossons();
jossons.putDataset("left", Josson.fromJsonString("{\n" +
        "\"package\": {\n" +
        "  \"institution\": [\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "        \"school\": \"TP\"\n" +
        "      }\n" +
        "    ],\n" +
        "    \"people\": [\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "        \"age\": 32,\n" +
        "        \"name\": \"Bob\"\n" +
        "      },\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "        \"age\": 16,\n" +
        "        \"name\": \"Amanda\"\n" +
        "      }\n" +
        "    ],\n" +
        "    \"details\": [\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "        \"course\": \"Humanities\",\n" +
        "        \"duration\": 4,\n" +
        "        \"description\": \"Students in Computer Sci\"\n" +
        "      }\n" +
        "    ]\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}"));
jossons.putDataset("right", Josson.fromJsonString("{\n" +
        "\"package\": {\n" +
        "  \"institution\": [\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "        \"school\": \"MIT\"\n" +
        "      }\n" +
        "    ],\n" +
        "    \"people\": [\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "        \"age\": 32,\n" +
        "        \"name\": \"Bob\"\n" +
        "      },\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "        \"age\": 16,\n" +
        "        \"name\": \"Samantha\"\n" +
        "      },\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "        \"age\": 20,\n" +
        "        \"name\": \"Dylan\"\n" +
        "      }\n" +
        "    ],\n" +
        "    \"details\": [\n" +
        "      {\n" +
        "        \"course\": \"Computer Sci\",\n" +
        "        \"duration\": 4,\n" +
        "        \"description\": \"Students in Computer Sci\"\n" +
        "      }\n" +
        "    ]\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}"));
JsonNode result = jossons.evaluateQuery("left->package >-> right->package");
System.out.println(result == null ? null : result.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "institution" : [ {
    "school" : "MIT"
  } ],
  "people" : [ {
    "age" : 16,
    "name" : "Samantha"
  }, {
    "age" : 20,
    "name" : "Dylan"
  } ],
  "details" : [ {
    "course" : "Computer Sci",
    "duration" : 4,
    "description" : "Students in Computer Sci"
  } ]
}
```